# In excel, how do I add X multiples Y years to a specific date once that date has passed?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

What formula should I use to automatically tell me my customer's next contract renewal date?

Example:
My customer has a policy that renews every 3 years, say 15-Feb-2021. I'd like the output of the formula to be 15-Feb-2021 up until that day, after which it automatically changes to 15-Feb-2024 (three years later) and when 15-2-2024 comes round the cell should automatically update to 15-Feb-2027 (being an additional three years later) and so on and so forth.

I have customers with varying contract lengths, so I'd like to be able to toggle the '3' years to another integer, e.g. 2 years, or 10 years.

Please can anyone help me build a formula that can do this?

Thank you

Comment: do the contracts always increment in years only ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=XLOOKUP(TODAY(),DATE(YEAR($A$2)+SEQUENCE(10,1,$B$2,$B$2),MONTH($A$2),DAY($A$2)),DATE(YEAR($A$2)+SEQUENCE(10,1,$B$2,$B$2),MONTH($A$2),DAY($A$2)),"",1,1)
```

There are two inputs here - the policy start date and the term.

[image]

The SEQUENCE creates a list of policy renewal dates. I have created 10, but you could put whatever integer you want in the first parameter of SEQUENCE if you need a longer lookup list. XLOOKUP then finds the item from the list that is the same or next largest from TODAY() and returns it in the yellow cell.

You don't actually need the data formula and data shown in column D - it's just there to illustrate the sequence of dates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an adaptation  of `FlexYourData`'s answer if you don't have Office 365.

Place the start date in **C1** and the yearly increment in **C2**.  In **C4** enter:

```
=DATE(YEAR(C$1)+(ROWS($1:1)-1)*C$2,MONTH(C$1),DAY(C$1))
```

Finally in **C3** enter the *Array formula*:

```
=MIN(IF(C4:C19>TODAY(),C4:C19))
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.